# Emmet expands css abbreviations as html

Tags: css, emmet

Everytime I expand an abbreviations on a css file it expands as html instead the proper css expansion.

This:

```
m10+p0
```

Should expand to this:

```
margin: 10px;
padding: 0px;
```

But instead expands to this:

```
<m10></m10>
<p0></p0>
```

I have installed the [Emmet mode](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode) using [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) with this config:

```
;; --- Emmet Mode ---
;; 
(use-package emmet-mode
  :ensure t

  :init
  (add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'emmet-mode) ;; Auto-start on any markup modes
  (add-hook 'css-mode-hook  'emmet-mode) ;; Enable Emmet's css abbreviation.
  (add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'emmet-mode) ;; Auto-start on any web modes

  :config
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-e w") nil)
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-e w") 'emmet-wrap-with-markup)      
  )
```

I tried disabling other packages but still does the same, even running the `M-x emmet-expand-line` instead of using the keybinding in case there's any collision on the keybindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit, it was a line on my web-mode use-package block.

```
;; --- Web-Mode ---
;; 
(use-package web-mode
  :mode (
     ("\\.php\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.html\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.htm\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.js\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.css\\'" . web-mode)   ;; <----Removed this one
     )
```

It seems web-mode was grabbing the control of the css files and trying to autocomplete the abbreviations as html. Now the css files are associated with the css-mode and emmet identifies this properly.